# Gettin error message 'NameError: global name 'randint' is not defined'

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, import, syntax-error

I have written a module memories.py using Python 2.7 (unfortunately, I cannot use the latest version due to some restriction). It looks as follows.

```
import random

    def get_a_random_memory(length, upper_sum_range, lower_sum_range):
        # Start with a blank memory
        memory = list()

        # For each bit along the length we add a random value
        for i in range(0, length):
            memory.append((2 * random.randint(0, 1) - 1))

        return memory
```

The error message is as follows.

```
>>> import memories    
>>> print memories.get_a_random_memory(5, 0, 10)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
      File "xyz\memories.py", line 21, in get_a_random_memory
        # For each bit along the length we add a random value
    NameError: global name 'randint' is not defined
```

Could anyone please help me out here?

Comment: do you have a module in that directory called random.py?

Comment: I don't have random.py in the same directory as memories.py. I do not know if it is in the python system.

Comment: What does `help(random)` return when you put it into the actual code?

Comment: You are not running the code you think you are. The above code would not give that error. You'll need to quit and re-open the shell.

Comment: @muddyfish, 'for i in range(0, length):
        print help(random)
        memory.append((2 * random.randint(0, 1) - 1))' doesn't output anything. print help(random) in the console gives 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'random' is not defined'

Comment: See @DanielRoseman's comment above.

Comment: Full code please and a project structure.